# How to convert old style Sql Outer join with condition to the new style

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to implement the old style SQL outer join with condition to the new style.

I am unable to convert the last line of the Join with condition.

Old Style Query:

```
SELECT cpd.customer_ref, cpd.product_seq, bci.contract_inst_id, 
bci.start_dat  bci_start_dat, bci.end_dat bci_end_dat 
FROM custproductdetails cpd, balcontractinstance bci
WHERE cpd.customer_ref = bci.customer_ref(+)
AND cpd.contract_seq = bci.contract_seq(+)
AND cpd.end_dat >=  bci.start_dat(+) AND cpd.end_dat <= bci.end_dat(+);
```

Comment: Show us your new style query attempt.

Comment: I want to have that query without the (+) notation.

Comment: Yes, I understand. What have you tried?

Comment: There are many more answers to this: https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&tab=Relevance&q=%5boracle%5d%20convert%20outer%20join

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are going from the oracle syntax to sqlserver etc, which requires the ansi syntax, which is better to use going forward in general, regardless of database

`Select a.a,b.a
From a left join b on a.a = b.a`

Is the same as

`Select a.a, b.a
From a, b
Where a.a = b.a(+)`

Comment: I could convert so far as shown below. Need idea on the last condition.

Comment: SELECT cpd.customer_ref,
 cpd.product_seq,
  bci.contract_inst_id,
  bci.start_dat bci_start_dat,
  bci.end_dat bci_end_dat
FROM custproductdetails cpd LEFT OUTER JOIN balcontractinstance bci ON cpd.customer_ref = bci.customer_ref AND cpd.contract_seq = bci.contract_seq

Comment: As I am planning to execute the above query in HIVE

Comment: What you have looks fine

Answer (score 0):

I believe this does what you want:

```
SELECT cpd.customer_ref, cpd.product_seq, bci.contract_inst_id, 
       bci.start_dat  bci_start_dat, bci.end_dat bci_end_dat 
FROM custproductdetails cpd LEFT JOIN
     balcontractinstance bci
     ON cpd.customer_ref = bci.customer_ref AND
        cpd.contract_seq = bci.contract_seq AND
        cpd.end_dat >=  bci.start_dat AND
        cpd.end_dat <= bci.end_dat;
```

The general rule is that the table referenced with the `(+)` gets additional rows added.  That makes it the second table in the `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It did work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Old Style Query:

```
SELECT cpd.customer_ref, cpd.product_seq, bci.contract_inst_id, 
    bci.start_dat  bci_start_dat, bci.end_dat bci_end_dat 
    FROM custproductdetails cpd, balcontractinstance bci
    WHERE cpd.customer_ref = bci.customer_ref(+)
    AND cpd.contract_seq = bci.contract_seq(+)
    AND cpd.end_dat >= bci.start_dat(+) 
    AND cpd.end_dat <= bci.end_dat(+);
```

'New' Style Query:

```
SELECT cpd.customer_ref, cpd.product_seq, bci.contract_inst_id, 
    bci.start_dat  bci_start_dat, bci.end_dat bci_end_dat 
    FROM custproductdetails cpd LEFT JOIN balcontractinstance bci
    ON cpd.customer_ref = bci.customer_ref
    AND cpd.contract_seq = bci.contract_seq
    AND cpd.end_dat >= bci.start_dat 
    AND cpd.end_dat <= bci.end_dat;
```

As you can see it's pretty similar.